# How to load multiple javascript files inside HTML page

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

I have many js files (say divided into set1 and set2), which are reused in multiple HTML and aspx pages. Using VS 2010.

I tried in head of the page1.html

```
< script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/set1.js">
< /script>
```

set1.js has:

```
/// < reference path="test11.js" />
/// < reference path="test12.js" />
```

All js files are in the Scripts folder of the VS solution.

Will the page1.html load both test11.js and test12.js . It seems to be not happening and i get  function (javascript function which i use on button events etc) undefined error while page loads.

What is the correct way to do it ? and what is the reference tag for ?

Comment: How do you see test11.js and test12.js are actually loaded?

Comment: @marcel because i get exception of js function undefined on page load.

Comment: In that case, they are *not* loaded.

Answer (score 2):

you have to include the scripts by using the `<script>` tag in the html `<head>`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="test11.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="test12.js"></script>
```

if you want to dynamically do this using javascript and jquery you could use the following example presuming you have an aray of javascript files you want to include:

example1 using jquery and javascript:

```
for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++)
{ 
    $head.append("<script src=\"" + scripts[i] + "\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script>")
};
```

example2: using only javascript without jquery:

```
for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++)
{ 
    var scriptElem=document.createElement('script')
    scriptElem.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
    scriptElem.setAttribute("src", scripts[i])
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(scriptElem)
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The reference tag is only for Intellisense completion (it's a comment, so JS ignores these lines).

You have to use the `<script>` tag for each script file you want to include.

Answer (score 1):

Put all your script references in the master-page head section - much easier to manage

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="x1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="x2.js"></script>
  ...
</head>
```

Comment: So if i am using same set of scripts set1 in 5-6 pages, then i will have to change in all 5-6 pages whenever i need to add or remove a js file. isnt there an indirection solution so that i make change only in 1 file (like set1.js) for easier maintenance. If there isnt any solution then i will go ahead with waht you siggested.

Comment: That's what the masterpage is for - create a masterpage and make all your aspx pages use the masterpage, then you have a single point of change.  Google asp.net masterpage for examples of how to do this.